# Package access level

Tags: c++

I'm wondering about how is it possible to set the package level access for a method in cpp.

Considering the following Java class

```
package Foo;
class Bar{
public Bar(){}
void bas(){}//package access, how in cpp?
}
```

the equivalent for cpp would be

```
namespace foo{

class bar{
public: bar(){};
//so now how would I set the package access specifier for bas?
};
};
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know C++ has not package access level modifiers. But maybe [friends class](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/inheritance/) will be usefull in your case?